# Dynamic variables in pandas using format

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to generate a slope in a dynamic way where I change the df name and the variable I use in linregress

```
list = ['a','b', 'c']
for i in list:
    '{}_slope'.format(i) = mydata.groupby(['group_a','group_b']).apply(lambda v: linregress(v.ym,'v.{}'.format(i))[0]).to_frame('a').reset_index()
```

I'm getting the following error:
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

how can I solve this topic?

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: When I tried using I still got an error in the linregress dynamic side

Comment: `d = {}` then `for i in list: d['{}_slope'.format(i)] = ...`